# Solving a Poisson series

Tags: sequences-and-series, poisson-distribution

I'm trying to find a neater expression for this sequence:

$$ \sum_{s \geq 0} e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{s}}{s!} sf(w)F(w)^{s-1} $$

where $f(w) = F'(w)$.

The following is my approach, but I think I did something horribly wrong with the sequence - I yield a factorial of $-1$ and don't know how to deal with that...

$$
 \\
 e^{-\lambda} f(w)\sum_{s \geq 0} \frac{\lambda^{s}}{(s-1)!} F(w)^{s-1}  \\
e^{-\lambda} f(w)\sum_{s \geq -1} \frac{\lambda^{s+1}}{s!} F(w)^{s}  \\
 \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda} f(w)\sum_{s \geq -1} \frac{\lambda^{s}}{s!} F(w)^{s}  \\
\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda} f(w)\left[ \frac{1}{-1!}F(w)^{-1} + \sum_{s \geq 0} \frac{\lambda^{s}}{s!} F(w)^{s}  \right]\\
 \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda} f(w)\left[ \frac{1}{-1!}F(w)^{-1} + e^{\lambda F(w)}\right] \\
 \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda}f(w)  \frac{1}{-1!}F(w)^{-1}  + \int \frac{e^{-\lambda (1 - F(w))}}{\lambda}f(w)\\
$$

Comment: What are $f$ and $F$? Is $F$ an antiderivative of $f$ or something? And what's $E$, is it expected value?

Comment: @Ian Sorry, $E$ should've been removed from this for simplicity. If it matters, $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$. I thought I'd keep the description short as I didn't think there would be much done using that.

Comment: Which antiderivative? It matters in this context. Or is it more that you are given $F$ and $f=F'$? In that case you should write it that way.

Comment: Basically, this is the expected maximum of drawing $s$ times from a distribution $F(w)$, where $s$ is Poisson distributed.

Comment: You should skip over the $s=0$ term which is just zero. Then you won't have any $(-1)!$. This is a very familiar trick (for example, it can be used to compute moments of the binomial distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may observe that the first term in your initial sum vanishes
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{s \geq 0} e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{s}}{s!} sf(w)F(w)^{s-1}&=\sum_{s \geq 1} e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{s}}{s!} sf(w)F(w)^{s-1}
\\\\&= f(w)\: \lambda e^{-\lambda}\sum_{s \geq 0}\frac{\lambda^{s}}{s!}F(w)^{s}
\\\\&=f(w)\: \lambda e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda F(w)}
\end{align}
$$ with a change of index in the last step.